# why is karate-testing 0.9.1 not available in maven central. I am trying to utilize one of the new feature "retry until"

Tags: karate

why is karate-testing 0.9.1 not available in maven central. I am trying to utilize one of the new feature "retry until". May I know timeline if available. Thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 1):

It is available, see for yourself:

https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-core/0.9.1/jar

No one else has reported this, so it is clearly some problem with your environment.

There is a section in the docs that explains how to bypass your corporate proxy, please try that: https://github.com/intuit/karate#quickstart